# How to compare QR result to my SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, if-statement, boolean, android-sqlite

I am creating an app where a QR code will be scanned and its result will compare it in the data that is inside the database.

I have tried creating a method that will return tru or false value in my database helper

```
public Boolean checkStudent(String student_number) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from student_table where student_number = ?", new String[]{student_number});

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Then on my main activity where the scanner and the results show i put this code

```
//button to call the scan function
        scan_btn = findViewById(R.id.fabScanner);
        scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    ScanOptions options = new ScanOptions();
                    options.setPrompt("Volume up to flash on");
                    options.setBeepEnabled(true);
                    options.setOrientationLocked(true);
                    options.setCaptureActivity(CaptureAct.class);
                    barLauncher.launch(options);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Scanner Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //insert the results of the scan ---> add a function that would check if qr result exist on the database
    ActivityResultLauncher<ScanOptions> barLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ScanContract(), result->
    {
        if(result.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "One more try", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            // get the content of the result
            String content = result.getContents();
            try {
                // set the result into different variables
                StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(content, ",");
                String number = tokens.nextToken();
                String name = tokens.nextToken();
                String time = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
                String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
                
                // check if the number exist on the database
                Boolean checkStudNum = myDatabaseHelper.checkStudent(number);
                if(checkStudNum) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setMessage(content)
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    myDatabaseHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                                    myDatabaseHelper.addAttendanceHistory(number.toUpperCase(), name.toUpperCase(), time.toUpperCase(), date.toUpperCase());
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "back to the start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid QR Code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

But somehow my code is goin in the "Invalid QR Code Exception", I genuinely do not know what is wrong as i have tried this method already in my other function and its working as expected.

My conjecture is that I'm having a problem in my boolean method.

```
// check if the number exist on the database
                Boolean checkStudNum = myDatabaseHelper.checkStudent(number);
                if(checkStudNum) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setMessage(content)
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    myDatabaseHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                                    myDatabaseHelper.addAttendanceHistory(number.toUpperCase(), name.toUpperCase(), time.toUpperCase(), date.toUpperCase());
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "back to the start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

My expected output is that if the qr result is similar to my data in my sqlite database it will insert the qr result into my database, and if its not similar it will show the "back to the start " exception. I'm a beginner in android mobile development and java language with sqlite database. So i dont really know what's causing a problem in my code. If you have any idea or fix, kindly comment!

Comment: If by `Invalid QR Code` you mean that the message is toasted, then I would suggest that you first output the actual exception that is being caught. e.g. add the line `e.printStackTrace();` immediately before the line `Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid QR Code" ....`. After the toast then check the log to see what exception was caught. The stack trace should indicate the code/line where the exception occurred.  Depending upon the cause you could then add breakpoints and inspect the code as you step through it. Perhaps refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/